# Sending emails with Thunderbird + Postfix + Zarafa does not work

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I installed zarafa on my vserver and use as MTA postfix.
The webaccess works fine, I can revceive and send emails, also receiving mails with thunderbird (IMAP ssl/tls) works.
But there is a problem, sending emails with thunderbird.
I established an account in thunderbird with imap ssl/tls connection which works finde,
and a starttls smtp connection on port 25 for the outgoing mail server.

If I try to send an email with thunderbird I get an error: 5.7.1 Relay access denied

this is my mail.log

```
Sep  7 16:10:07 postfix/smtpd[6153]: connect from p4FE06C0A.dip.t-dialin.net[79.224.110.10]
Sep  7 16:10:08 postfix/smtpd[6153]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from p4FE06C0A.dip.t-dialin.net[79.224.110.10]: 554 5.7.1 <mail@adress.com>: Relay access denie$
Sep  7 16:10:10 postfix/smtpd[6153]: disconnect from p4FE06C0A.dip.t-dialin.net[79.224.110.10]
```

and this my /etc/postfix/main.conf

```
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

virtual_mailbox_domains = firstdomain.de, seconddomain.de
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_transport = lmtp:127.0.0.1:2003
myhostname = mail.firstdomain.de
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

I don't know what to do, because actually sending mails to internal and external addresses works with the webaccess.

Perhaps somebody can help me?

Comment: Your log is truncated. Please provide the entire log message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you like to set up SMTP authentication on your mail server, but your Postfix configuration does not show any authentication configuration for clients. You could do this using SASL against the Zarafa-gateway (IMAP) like described [here](http://www.zarafa.com/wiki/index.php/SMTP-Auth_for_IMAP_users). Then configure Postfix to use your SASL (Cyrus for example) and 'trust' authenticated clients. Read more about that in the [Postfix SASL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl) (part 'Mail relay authorization' in particular).

This way, all IMAP enabled users in Zarafa will have authorized SMTP relay access on your MTA.